# iOS 'set up iad network' button missing

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

I am trying to set my app to use iAds but there are some problems.  I followed  [this](http://www.appsvolcano.com/index.php/support/how-to-make-own-mobile-apps-for-iphone-android-kindle-ipad?catid=4&faqid=51)  tutorial and got stuck on step three cause the button isn't available for me.

I'm not entirely sure why.  I already filled up the paperwork, tax and contracts info.  But the button is not there.  Has it been moved?

A few months ago the button WAS there, however after I clicked it and enabled it, it tells me that I can only enable it when the app is in review.  Ok now back to the present, I submit my app that has iAds in it.  And it is waiting to be reviewed.  The button to enable iAds is missing.  It's been a week already.  The app already got approved and is available, yet the button is not there.  I'm not sure how else to enable iAds.

I have tried going to the iAd network site but all it tells me is that iAd network is temporarily unavailable.  It's been already a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a response from apple regarding this issue.

They are no longer using the enable iAd button.  As long as you have the paperwork and the iAd framework it should work.

I already have the paperwork done so they tell me that my implementation is wrong.

So I stopped using interface builder for my adds and instead just did it all programmatically.

I don't know if it will make a difference.  We shall see... After my app gets approved I'll let ya know....

Answer (score 0):

I have also recently started implementing iAd in my apps. I have published three apps with iAd and did not see the button in iTunes Connect. The test ads work, however, I have not been able to test whether the ads work on a non provisioned device yet.I have also noticed the iAd module giving me the "iAd Network is temporarily unavailable" error message. I have seen it for at least five days now.

**Update:** My apps are finally being served iAds. What I did was simply release an update. I didn't even change my code for the ads. I am also not seeing the error from iAd that they can't find my account info; I'm just seeing revenue.

Comment: I finally got iAds working.  Here's what I did:  made it run on iOS 7 and up.  Then I set the canDisplayBannerAds property to yes.  It is a little more Automatic and you lose the ability to use the adbannerdelegate but it works.  It worked one day after it was available.

Comment: I simply released an update for my apps. That seemed to fix it even though the updated content was simply a pop up asking the user to rate the app.

Answer (score 0):

I simply updated the apps that were supposed to have ads from iAd, and now they are working. It seems that Apple is having quite a few issues with their servers at the moment, though.